# Finding the average of 3 data sets with different number of data points and plotting the average curve

Tags: excel, excel-formula, graph, average

I have [3 sets of data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NbEUWDrRg1boYKfdkYCNCZHLQ1N0Mh49/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104691425985368324241&rtpof=true&sd=true) but with a different number of data points as the tests ran for various lengths of time. The end goal is to get the average of the 3 graphs. I posted a picture of the graph that I need to average out with the three separate tests. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY63O.png)

I tried both average functions, averageif functions and the plot had 3 "fangs" instead of one coherent line when averaging this way.

[image]

Comment: Why not compare or average the time as a base?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, If test 1 runs for 7.6 seconds, test 2 runs for 8.7 seconds, and test 3 runs for 8.3 seconds. How would I go about lining up the varying lengths of data? Also, I'm not plotting time in the graph, so does doing so even help?

Answer (score 1):

This function combines all your ranges:

```
=Let(firstGroup,B4:D,secondGroup,F4:G,thirdGroup,J4:L,VSTACK(filter(firstGroup,isnumber(index(firstGroup,,1))),  filter(secondGroup,isnumber(index(secondGroup,,1))), filter(thirdGroup,isnumber(index(thirdGroup,,1)))))
```

From there you should be able to create the graph with a single fang...

[image]

Comment: Wow. This is absolutely nice!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I guess I'm confused on how combining all of the ranges and plotting simultaneous will obtain the average of the three data sets?

Comment: I just panicked when I saw your three-fanged snake, so I thought this would help. Maybe you ought to review SO's [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) terms so people don't waste any more time trying to provide a solution that apparently isn't helpful.

Comment: Sir, your solution worked for me, i have tried with OP's data. I have downloaded the google sheet and used the formula in excel. And since I like this community StackOverflow, i try to follow all solutions VBA or Excel, and immediately try in excel, it helps me to learn and gain knowledge.